# How to change order_by clause in Flask-SQLAlchemy based on dropdown box selection?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I would like to give users on my site the ability to change the order of the results obtained from a query in my database (for example alphabetically ascending, alphabetically descending, or by another parameter).

This is the query I would like to perform an order_by on:

```
def get_curators_and_total_followers():
    total_playlist_followers =  db.session.query(SpotifyPlaylist.curator_id.label('user_id'), db.func.sum(SpotifyPlaylist.playlist_follower_count).label("total_followers"))\
        .outerjoin(User, SpotifyPlaylist.curator_id==User.id)\
        .group_by(User.id)\
        .subquery()
    curators = db.session.query(User, total_playlist_followers.c.total_followers)\
        .outerjoin(total_playlist_followers, User.id==total_playlist_followers.c.user_id)\
        .join(SpotifyPlaylist, SpotifyPlaylist.curator_id==User.id)\
        .order_by("This is where I want to change the fields")   
    return curators
```

How can I set a default value so that the page loads, then give users the option to display the results in a different way based on a dropdown box with a few different order_by options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_curators_and_total_followers():
    total_playlist_followers =  db.session.query(SpotifyPlaylist.curator_id.label('user_id'), db.func.sum(SpotifyPlaylist.playlist_follower_count).label("total_followers"))\
        .outerjoin(User, SpotifyPlaylist.curator_id==User.id)\
        .group_by(User.id)\
        .subquery()
    curators = db.session.query(User, total_playlist_followers.c.total_followers)\
        .outerjoin(total_playlist_followers, User.id==total_playlist_followers.c.user_id)\
        .join(SpotifyPlaylist, SpotifyPlaylist.curator_id==User.id)\
    
    order_by = form.get('orderBy')
    if order_by is None:
        curators.order_by("your default value")
    else:
        curators.order_by(order_by)
        
    return curators
```

Comment: I'm going to try to implement this but wouldn't I need to pass "form" to the function?

Comment: sure you should get the form from request.

Comment: I was able to get it! Only problem is that the options in my dropdown reset once the page reloads. Any suggestions?

Comment: ```python
@app.route("/curators", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def curators():
    user = get_user_by_email_or_404(current_user)
    form = None
    order_by_form = None
    curators = get_curators_and_total_followers(order_by_form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_by_form = request.form["order-by"]
        curators = get_curators_and_total_followers(order_by_form)
    return render_template("curators.html", title="Curators", curators=curators)```

Comment: do something like this: `if method is POST you should set drop down default value to order_by_form that you get in the request`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528644/having-a-select-option-stay-selected-after-post-with-flask